# DIN Rail Splitter?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

We have a DIN rail with multiple terminal blocks on it, used to extend circuits from their original location to a new location a few feet away. This is all fine and proper for the most part. The issue is that a couple of the blocks have been double tapped, and I'd like to fix this.

I'm looking for a DIN rail terminal block that will split 1 incoming wire into multiple (3) outgoing wires so that I can fix the double and triple taps that are happening.

I have looked at Mouser but I didn't see anything promising there. Is there a terminal block that will allow me to split a 2AWG 600V rated wire into multiple outgoing wires? I'm sure this must exist, but I'm having a hard time finding something that fits the need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There do exist DIN terminal blocks that can be bridged so that multiple positions are connected. Some styles use a small metal plate with a screw to fasten to each terminal position; others use a plug-in jumper style; some of the plug-in style even support removal of legs in the middle so that non-adjacent terminal positions can be bridged.

A shopping question "find a product that meets X criteria for me" would be off-topic, but I could suggest to look at the catalogs for Phoenix Contact or TE Connectivity for example to explore their offerings. Sometimes it's easier to find what you need by searching a manufacturer's site rather than the distributor catalog. Searching for terms like "jumper" or "bridge" could lead you to the product families that support that feature. Whether there's a family with bridge support that also accommodates 2 AWG wire or a specific ampacity, I couldn't say. Certainly they do have offerings for 600V and beyond.

Comment: Yes the blocks combine multiple units, just make sure to get the same brand as different brands are slightly different, most come in strips of 10 you cut how many you need. +